# How to get X/Y position of touch in iPhone Safari?

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, position

I'm having a bit of a problem figuring out how to get the X/Y coordinates of where the finger is touching in a webapp on iPhone Safari.

I've got a function subscribed to the 'touchstart', 'touchmove', and 'touchend' events, and I have tried pageX/pageY on the event but can't seem to get anything other than 'undefined' or 0.

I'm also thinking my keyword searching isn't quite right because I haven't found any clear documentation on exactly how to do this, anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation you're looking for is here:

[Apple Web Content Guide: Handling Multi-Touch Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW22)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have basic x/y detection going on now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
client.Y and client.X
```

To get the coordinates of `X` and `Y`.

Comment: that client object is not available on a touch event. If you have a touch event you can access the touches by the touches list : event.touches[i].clientX & ...clientY. You should also consider whether you truly need pageX/Y or clientX/Y!